# Select Records from INNER JOINed table only ONCE

Tags: mysql

```
$Sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Schedule_ID = Table2.SheduleId WHERE Table1.ID = '$id' AND Table2.Scheduled = '1'";
```

The rows in `Table1` are only selected if `Table1.Schedule_ID` has the same value as a record  in `Table2.SheduleId`. For TWO values in `Table1` it selects the same row TWICE from `Table2`. I'd like to avoid that and make each row from `Table2` `SELECT`-able only once.

I tried `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1` but to no avail.

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: And what row should be selected from table2 if 2 records exist? You need to tell the the DB in your query

Comment: So you have two rows in `Table2` which have the same value for `SheduleId` and the two rows don't contain the same data (or else the `DISTINCT *` would have probably taken care of it for you). So which row is right and which one isn't? This is not a problem anyone here can fix - you're going to have to go into your database, figure out which row is right, and get rid of the other one. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. The two rows may be selected, but I'd like each row in the query to only be used once. (not to be used for two rows in Table1). If I'm making sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well  please try this modification:

```
$Sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Table2.* FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Schedule_ID = Table2.SheduleId WHERE Table1.ID = '$id' AND Table2.Scheduled = '1'";
```

I hope it will help in any way.